# Issues Creating a folder in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Hoping someone can help me with an issue i am encountering.

I have gui created which allows folder creation, checking folder access and adding permissions to groups. I have all parts working bar the folder creation. It fails with various errors. So i decided to test the code on its own. I ran all as Domain Admin so permissions shouldn't be an issue.

Command i am using:

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path '\\Server1\Users\Username'
```

When i run the above the folder creates fine no issues. In my script it fails or seems to place the directory called my Variable in the location the log files go. ( Ill post code further down). So i decided to try on its own with the below:

```
$NewPath = '\\Server1\Users\Username'

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path '$NewPath'
```

I seem to get the below error:

```
New-Item : Access to the path '$NewPath' is denied.
At C:\Users\*******\Downloads\Test.ps1:3 char:1
+ New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path '$NewPath'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\******\$NewPath:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

My admin account has Local Admin access to my PC as well so shouldn't be any issues there.

My code in my Gui is

```
#Function creates a new folder in location specificed in gui.
function CreateFolder { 

    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path '$NewPath.text'
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('New Path has been created' ,'New Path has been created','OK')

}
```

The Gui Entries are below:

```
    $Create                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Create.text                     = "Create Folders"
    $Create.AutoSize                 = $true
    $Create.width                    = 25
    $Create.height                   = 10
    $Create.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(507,10)
    $Create.Font                     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]([System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold))
    
    $NewFolderPath                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
    $NewFolderPath.text              = "New Folder Path"
    $NewFolderPath.AutoSize          = $true
    $NewFolderPath.width             = 25
    $NewFolderPath.height            = 10
    $NewFolderPath.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(407,118)
    $NewFolderPath.Font              = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
    
    $NewPath                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $NewPath.multiline               = $false
    $NewPath.width                   = 153
    $NewPath.height                  = 20
    $NewPath.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(391,161)
    $NewPath.Font                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
    $CreateFolder                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CreateFolder.text               = "Create"
    $CreateFolder.width              = 83
    $CreateFolder.height             = 61
    $CreateFolder.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(594,124)
    $CreateFolder.Font               = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
    $CreateFolder.BackColor          = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#ec1212")
```

Thanks all. Really bugging me. Tried various combinations and all fails. I run the command with path from PS and it runs fine and creates the folder.

Current error for information is below when run from gui:

```
New-Item : Access to the path '$NewPath.text' is denied.
At C:\TestScripts\FolderPermissonTool.ps1:231 char:5
+     New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path '$NewPath.text'
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\******\$NewPath.text:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Thanks

Comment: Variables are not interpolated in single-quoted strings. The quotation isn't required at all: `New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $NewPath`

Comment: Try changing `'$NewPath'` to `"$NewPath"` - PowerShell does not expand variables in strings that are single-quoted, but does if they're double-quoted.

Comment: Thank you @zett42 that's done it... Never thought to try without as some paths will have spaces and PS tends to not like those without being quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zett42's answer fixed it.

Variables are not interpolated in single-quoted strings. The quotation isn't required at all: `New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $NewPath` – zett42

Appreciate the help.